# How to get all country with city and state in Laravel Database

Tags: database, laravel

I have 3 tables Country , State and City 
They are interrelated like each state has one country and each city has one state 
I want to know If I can get all the data of world like all country with their state and city filled up with relationship too in my laravel Application . I want to know if there are any factory library for that If Yes How ???

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can make relations between them.

**Country model:**

```
public function states(){
     return $this->hasMany(State::class);
}

public function statesWithCities(){
     return $this->states()->with('cities');
}
```

**State model:**

```
public function cities(){
     return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}

public function country(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

**City model:**

```
public function state(){
     return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
```

and you can get all Countries , states , cities with below code:

```
Country::latest()->with('statesWithCities')->get()
```